# Can you setup multiple ad hoc networks at once?

Tags: ad-hoc-network

I want to connect 4 or more laptops to an ad hoc network but from what I’ve read an ad hoc network uses 1 of the laptops as a host. If that is the case then I think that would mean that transferring data between laptops would all have to go through the host which would slow the host laptop down. Instead, I want to make separate ad hoc connections from each laptop to the other ones so that each laptop can act as their own temporary host when data is being transferred. Can I setup multiple ad hoc connections like that?

Comment: Is this about wifi? Which platform are you on? Win/osx/linux? What is the network type, A/B/G/N/something else?

The more details you can give, the better answer you will have.

Comment: Unclear: If all the computers can connect directly, why do you need ad hoc network(s)?

Comment: By connecting directly, I mean using an ad hoc network with only the two computers who are talking connected to that one network instead of only one ad hoc network with all 4 computers connected.

Comment: I am on Linux mint. I don’t know what network type it is. What is the A/B/G/N stuff?

Comment: On each laptop assign a static IP address. Get an Ethernet switch, and connect each laptop to it.  Instant *ad hoc* network where each laptop can access any other laptop. There is no central *"host"*

Comment: But if all the computers want to talk at once (a wants to talk to b and c wants to talk to d) won’t an Ethernet switch only let one talk at a time?

Comment: No, you're thinking of a hub.

Comment: I thought a switch was like a cpu where it looks like it’s doing two things at once but it’s actually doing them one at a time really fast.

Comment: Does a switch have multiple processors or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to connect 4 or more laptops to an ad hoc network but from what I’ve read an ad hoc network uses 1 of the laptops as a host.

No, 'ad-hoc' networks don't work like that – only 'infrastructure' networks do (the usual kind).

But the problem is that actual `ad-hoc` type networks were poorly supported, they had security issues (couldn't use WPA at first), and became kind of forgotten. Nowadays, when you start up a "hotspot" network from a laptop or a smartphone, that might be called ad-hoc in English, but it is usually *not* an `ad-hoc` type network in Wi-Fi terms.

Instead, new phones and laptops actually create `infrastructure` type networks, where everything indeed goes through the central device (the "access point"). This is the exact same type that everyone's home wifi router uses.

But one point about ad-hoc networks is that they do put all devices on the same radio frequency (i.e. the same Wi-Fi channel), and radio is a shared medium. So it *is* actually true that only one device can speak at a time – even if you have direct transfers going on between A-B and C-D, they can't both happen at once on the same frequency, no matter the network type.

---

So if you're looking for speed, I second the recommendation of using wired Ethernet and a switch. All modern Ethernet switches can do what you want.

> But if all the computers want to talk at once (a wants to talk to b and c wants to talk to d) won’t an Ethernet switch only let one talk at a time?

No, switched Ethernet is not a shared medium – the switch allows all devices to talk to each other at once, as long as there is capacity for that.

> I thought a switch was like a cpu where it looks like it’s doing two things at once but it’s actually doing them one at a time really fast.

I don't know how hardware switching circuits are built. But even if this is the case, as long it's doing those things *fast enough*, you won't be able to tell the difference anyway.

For example, if you buy a 24-port gigabit switch, it will usually say "48 Gbps switching capacity" in the specs. Meaning, it can handle the full 1 Gbps going in *and* out through every single port at the same time. It doesn't actually matter if it's handling one port at a time really fast – at this point it's not the switching core that becomes the bottleneck, it's the ports themselves that can't go above 1 Gbps anyway.

Most Gigabit Ethernet switches on the market nowadays have enough capacity to handle all ports at full speed.